How to include authentication headers in visual studio .http file?
I'm trying to connect to MongoDB Ops Manager programmatically, and so I have a public and private key that I generated. When I use the key details and make a request through insomnia using digest protocol, I get a successful response, however, when I use .http file in visual studio I get a 401 Unauthorized error.
.http file-
@OpsManager_HostAddress = https://mongops.dummy.company:8443

### Ops Manager. Digest Auth
GET {{OpsManager_HostAddress}}/api/public/v1.0
Authorization: Digest <public>:<private>
Accept: application/json

### Ops-Manager Basic Auth
GET {{OpsManager_HostAddress}}/api/public/v1.0
Authorization: Basic <ikulhasdb***FAKE***likhashdk>
Accept: application/json

I tried creating a env.json file to put the secrets there but doesn't seem to work as well-
ASP.NET Core user secrets- Unclear how to use private/public key
I'm new to using the .http file so If someone can guide me in the right direction on how to use the auth headers? Thanks!
